# Fetch an image from OneDrive Business by ID using Graph API using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, onedrive-for-business, microsoft-graph

I'm attempting to retrieve an image from my OneDrive via the Microsoft Graph API. I made sure to have all the necessary permissions to do so. This has worked in the past, but now it's returning error code 0. Here's my GET request:

```
$RequestHeader = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $authToken"
    "Content-Type" = "image/jpeg"
}

$OneDriveUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/[drive-url]/items/[image-onedriveid]/content"

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $OneDriveUrl -Method Get -Headers $RequestHeader -OutFile "newpicture.jpeg"
```

This should retrieve the picture into the current folder and name it "newpicture.jpeg".
I know for a fact that this has worked before because on the 1st of April I ran the same exact code (although with a different picture id) on the same drive and it retrieved a picture:

[image: earlier-run]

Has Microsoft been playing around with the OneDrive graph API? I recall that the "/content" at the end was not in the relevant [documentation for this specific case](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_get?view=odsp-graph-online). I believe I found that on a Stack Overflow thread about something similar, although it was working as intended.
Is there any way around this? If I remove the "/content" at the end I do received general information about that item, but at that point I don't need the relevant information, only the picture itself.

Am I missing something? Does anyone know a way around this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think the endpoint must have had some trouble. It's working as intended now.